# Proof of product summation of binomial coefficients

Tags: summation, induction, binomial-coefficients, negative-binomial

when I try to proof the sum of two independent negative binomial distribution to be negative binomial, I end up with how to proof the following identity. I try the induction but after I rearrange the terms and use C(n, m)=C(n-1,m-1)+C(n-1,m), it still not completely finish the proof. could you please give me some hint? Thank you.

Proof

> $$\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{j+r-1}{j}\cdot\binom{k-j+s-1}{k-j} = \binom{k+r+s-1}{k}$$

[Source.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyJEG.png)

Comment: 1) Here we use latex for math formulas. 2)You forgot what identity wants to prove?

Comment: thank you for the editing...now the identity is shown..

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity

Comment: it is not the same, the dummy index in this problem appears at both top and bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we have a *[Chu-Vandermonde identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity#Chu%E2%80%93Vandermonde_identity)*
in disguise.

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{j=0}^k}&\color{blue}{\binom{j+r-1}{j}\binom{k-j+s-1}{k-j}}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^{k}\binom{-r}{j}(-1)^j\binom{-s}{k-j}(-1)^{k-j}\tag{1}\\
> &=\binom{-(r+s)}{k}(-1)^k\tag{2}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{= \binom{r+s+k-1}{k}}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the binomial identity $\binom{-n}{k}(-1)^k=\binom{n+k-1}{k}$ twice.
- In (2) we apply the *[Chu-Vandermonde identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity#Chu%E2%80%93Vandermonde_identity)*
  .
- In (3) we apply the binomial identity from (1) again.

Comment: thank you, I am wondering if I can use induction to proof it directly, without using the upper negation?

Comment: @mathfans: A proof by induction using the upper negation is perfectly valid. It's often convenient to transform the expression and reduce complicated parts before applying the induction step. We shouldn't stick at the complicated situation, if a more elegant approach is accessible. Regards,